# Capistrano 3 deploys to all servers defined in stage config file, even if the server role is not included in deploy namespace

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

There are two main jobs to be done, each with their own namespace.

The first deploys the symfony app as you'd expect.

The second updates the databases on the server designated with the `db` role from the server designated with the `source` role.

After adding this second job to the deploy script (updating the dbs), the standard `cap staging deploy` command deploys the app to `staging` *and* `www` (production) even though all tasks in the deploy namespace point to the `web` role.

Did I miss something in the capistrano documentation? Any suggestions?

staging.rb

```
server 'staging.thesite.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web db}

# source role defines the machine from where the db will be pulled from
server 'www.thesite.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{source}
```

deploy.rb

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2d821924f03e56de839e

Comment: Same problem here, also with a `doctrine:migrations:migrate`! Have you found a solution? #fingercrossed